# How to use shadow catcher in animation render?

Tags: rendering, shadowcatcher

I struggle to use a simple shadow catcher option on a plane, 
If I render a single frame everything works perfectly: 
[image]

but if I render an animation, the shadow catcher option on my plane doesn't work: 
[image]

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine for me. Can you upload your file and I can take a look

Comment: Well, I try different things. My first render was on a Hackintosh, looks like to had the issue with my GPU. The functionality works well on a normal computer.